# Remove comma in between each word in file

Tags: python

My problem is after running my code came expected output, but in file contains comma between each words.

My input file:

```
idNo;UserGroup;Name;Description;Owner;Visibility;Members
id;grp1;bhalaji;asdfgh;bhalaji;public
abc
def
ghi
id;grp2;bhalaji;asdfgh;bhalaji;private
abc
def
ghi
```

My code:

```
import csv
output = []
temp = []
currIdLine = ""
with( open ('usergroups.csv', 'r')) as f:
    for lines in f.readlines():
        line = lines.strip()
        if not line:
            print("Skipping empty line")
            continue
        if line.startswith('idNo'): # append the header to the output
            output.append(line)
            continue
        if line.startswith('id'):
            if temp:
                print(temp)
                output.append(currIdLine + ";" + ','.join(temp))
                temp.clear()
            currIdLine = line
        else:
            temp.append(line)
output.append(currIdLine + ";" + ','.join(temp))
print("\n".join(output))
with open('new.csv', 'w') as f1:
    writer = csv.writer(f1)
    writer.writerows(output)
```

Output of the code:

```
u,u,i,d,;,U,s,e,r,G,r,o,u,p,;,N,a,m,e,;,D,e,s,c,r,i,p,t,i,o,n,;,O,w,n,e,r,;,V,i,s,i,b,i,l,i,t,y,;,M,e,m,b,e,r,s ---> heading
i,d,:;,g,r,p,1,;,b,h,a,l,a,j,i,;,a,s,d,f,g,h,;,b,h,a,l,a,j,i,;,p,u,b,l,i,c,;,a,b,c,,d,e,f,,g,h,i
i,d,:;,g,r,p,2,;,b,h,a,l,a,j,i,;,a,s,d,f,g,h,;,b,h,a,l,a,j,i,;,p,r,i,v,a,t,e,;,a,b,c,,d,e,f,,g,h,i
```

My desired output:

```
uuid;UserGroup;Name;Description;Owner;Visibility;Members
id:grp1;bhalaji;asdfgh;bhalaji;public;abc,def,ghi
id:grp2;bhalaji;asdfgh;bhalaji;private;abc,def,ghi
```

I don't know what is the issue in my code. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try using `''.join(temp)` without comma

Comment: @AbhishekKumar i have tried, but getting same output

Comment: It is always convenient to provide link to your source file (in your case `.csv` file) so that community user can focus on problem only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows

`writerows(rows)` takes a list of lists, but in your code it is a list of strings.

I don't think you need the csv module at all.

```
with open('new.csv', 'w') as f1:
    for row in output:
        f1.write(row + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking advantage of [`range(start, stop, step=1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) step, this becomes pretty easy.

```py
obj = """idNo;UserGroup;Name;Description;Owner;Visibility;Members
id;grp1;bhalaji;asdfgh;bhalaji;public
abc
def
ghi
id;grp2;bhalaji;asdfgh;bhalaji;private
abc
def
ghi
"""

lines = obj.strip().split("\n")
output = [lines[0]]

for i in range(1, len(lines), 4):
    output.append(lines[i] + ";" + ",".join(lines[i + 1 : i + 4]))

print("\n".join(output))
```

```
idNo;UserGroup;Name;Description;Owner;Visibility;Members
id:grp1;grp1;bhalaji;asdfgh;bhalaji;public;abc,def,ghi
id:grp2;grp2;bhalaji;asdfgh;bhalaji;private;abc,def,ghi
```